# Angular mat-table cancel ripple

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have an angular-material table with a clickable row with matRipple effect.
Within the table I have a button as one of the rows.
When the button is clicked it emits an event, and so far I have stopped event propagation and this works well at preventing both elements from detecting the a click event.
Is there a way of cancelling the ripple effect of the parent row momentarily ONLY when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ripple uses the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events, and you can disable or turn on the parent's ripple in both events:

```
  <div
    class="example-ripple-container mat-elevation-z4"
    matRipple
    [matRippleDisabled]="disabled"
  >
    <button (mousedown)="disabled=true" (mouseup)="disabled=false" mat-button>button</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply stop further propagation of the button's mousedown event using [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method, as demonstrated below:

```
<button (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()">
```